# Erorr while installing angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am new to angular. Firstly I install node js in my machine and after that I followed [this](https://cli.angular.io) url to install angular but I got following error

gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH

gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python

gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Tejal.Pawar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)

gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Tejal.Pawar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)

Do I need to install python too? or should I ignore it ?

Comment: I've never needed to install python to use Angular.  What command are you running exactly to get those errors?

Comment: I used npm install -g @angular/cli command

Comment: this one is related to node maybe can you tell us what is the version of node taht instaled on your machine ?? node -v

Comment: @MuhammadAlbarmawi I installed v8.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Angular required at least node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x,
you can flow these steps,currently I'm using the latest version Angular 5.2.x

1. install Node v8.x.x
2. npm install  windows-build-tools@1.3.2 -g
3. npm install @angular-devkit/core@0.0.28 -g
4. npm install @angular/cli@1.7.3 -g
5. happy coding :)